# Issue with Labeled Bar Percents and Missing Bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

This line of code,

```
ggplot(Oak, aes(x= age,  group=subject_talk)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat = "count") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. ), 
            stat = "count", vjust = -0.5) + 
  labs(y = "Percent", fill = "subject_talk") + 
  facet_grid(~subject_talk) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) + 
  xlim(40,49)
```

gives me the image[image].

I want the x-axis limited to 40-49, but the bar for 49 isn't showing up (there isn't one for 40); furthermore, there are percents floating above the outermost edges of each graph, which I don't want.

Thanks.

Comment: The bar for 49 is centered at 49. If you cut the axis at 49, there's not enough room for it. Give it a little cushion - try 49.5. Or maybe use a discrete x-axis?

Comment: If you need more help than that, you'll probably need to share a bit of data. `dput()` is nice for making a copy/pasteable version of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Gregor Thomas's suggestion.

Changing the code to this,

```r
ggplot(Oak, aes(x = age, group = subject_talk)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat = "count") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop..), stat = "count", vjust = -.5) + 
    labs(y = "Percent", fill = "subject_talk") + 
    facet_grid(~ subject_talk) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
    xlim(39.1, 49.9)
```

fixes both problems.

I used `xlim(39.1, 49.9)` which gave the bars enough space to show up. The floating percentages also disappear.